# How can i get all files without file extension into an array

Tags: asp.net, directoryinfo

How can i get all files without file extension into an array. I will supply the folder path.
Is this possible using Directory.GetFiles() or DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()?? Is there any alternative way?

I am using ASP.NET C#.

Comment: Is there more to this question than is apparent? Use Directory.GetFiles to get the list of files, iterate over the returned values looking for files that don't have any extension, collect those into an array?

Comment: Do you want to find all files that do not have an extension, or put all files, regardless of extension, into an array, minus their extensions?  Did that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.")
```

(now verified; that works fine) - note that you may need to use `Server.MapPath` to switch between relative site paths and physical disk paths, and that the results of `Directory.GetFiles` are full paths.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get just the name part of all files in a folder (even those with extensions):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir,"*.*")
                          .Select(n => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(n))
                          .ToArray();
```